# Facebook - Heroku - Tab Issues

Tags: facebook, heroku, tabs

having a problem using Facebook's Heroku Integration.

I've got a business page, which I want a "Facebok Tab" on, which links to a schedule.

From what I understand, I've had to setup a facebook app in the developer area, and setup the canvas's to point to my hosted files. which are located at https://warm-mist-9082.herokuapp.com/ my facebook namespace for the app is currently setup as https://apps.facebook.com/weblessoncrashes/.

Inside the app I've setup the Tab url as https://warm-mist-9082.herokuapp.com/lessons.php

So theoretically when I click my tab ( https://www.facebook.com/WebIsEasy/app_388846884472817 )

it should load the contents of lessons.php which is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hihi</title>
</head>
<body>
nonono
</body>
</html>
```

however. What you in reality will see is just a facebook frame with a blank canvas within.

I have tried varying the tabs to use the facebook namespace, and checked all the SSL certs and entries are correct.

I've now come to a stand still.

Any help would be perfect!

Thanks

Comment: A bit confused. If lessons.php is your app why not have it as "/"

Comment: Are you even using the PHP setup heroku gave you or did you scratch everything out?

Comment: @phwd I thought you needed to separate the tabs from the main app, but either way its irrelevant isn't it to which page it loads from? and yes Im using the heroku files that it gave me from setting it up following their documentation

Comment: Okay I was reading it wrong sorry about that. Started a new app using the PHP flow then pushed a lessons.php file, switched the setting for Page Tab URL and Secure Tab URL and it worked. So I guess it's most likely a setting you have different or it could be just a matter of removing the tab and adding it back to the page. Lots of shooting in the dark (at least for me) if you want I could chat it out on irc.freenode #facebook to get closer to where the problem could be

Comment: ah well i deleted it all and started from scratch and it worked. so who knows what went wrong!